# Ada protected types

Tags: function, ada, procedure

I've got a simple package in Ada with procedures and functions.  I'd like to have all the functions and procedures in a protected type.

e.g. for a simple .adb file

```
package body Pack is

  procedure procedure1 (B : in out Integer) is
  begin
    B := new Integer;
  end procedure1;

  procedure procedure2 (B: in out Integer) is
  begin
    B.Cont(B.First-1) := 1;
  end procedure2;

  function procedure3 (B : Integer) return Boolean is
  begin
    return B.First = B.Last;
  end procedure3;

end pack;
```

and or a simple .ads

```
package body Pack is

   procedure procedure1 (B : in out Integer);

   procedure procedure2 (B: in out Integer);

   function procedure3 (B : Integer) return Boolean;

end pack;
```

How would I go about it?

Comment: That code is a long way from compiling. In `procedure1`, B is declared as `Integer` but you then assign an access value to it (`new Integer`). And in the other two subprograms, B appears to be a record type. And the reserved word `body` can’t appear in a package spec.

Comment: 1> This is not valid Ada code. 2> Did you mean a protected type as in concurrency ? if so read here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_%28programming_language%29#Concurrency

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The thing about a protected type is that it protects something (against concurrent access). It’s hard to see from your code what it is you want to protect.

If, say, you wanted to do a thread-safe increment, you might have a spec like

```
package Pack is
   protected type T is
      procedure Set (To : Integer);
      procedure Increment (By : Integer);
      function Get return Integer;
   private
      Value : Integer := 0;
   end T;
end Pack;
```

(this is far from perfect; you’d like to be able to specify the initial `Value` when you declare a `T`, but that’s starting to get complicated).

In this case, the thing to be protected is the `Value`. You want to be sure that if two tasks call `Increment` at the “same” time, one with `By => 3` and one with `By => 4`, the `Value` ends up being incremented by 7.

The body could look like

```
package body Pack is
   protected body T is
      procedure Set (To : Integer) is
      begin
         Value := To;
      end Set;
      procedure Increment (By : Integer) is
      begin
         Value := Value + By;
      end Increment;
      function Get return Integer is
      begin
         return Value;
      end Get;
   end T;
end Pack;
```

Recommended reading: the [Wikibooks section](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Tasking#Protected_types) on protected types.

Comment: + 1 for a better link than mine :)

Comment: You could even hide the protected object inside the package body, just keeping the specs of wrapper subprograms in the spec file.